# What's the reason behind the jumping GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE) when not specifying a @TableGenerator?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Why do I need to add allocationSize=1 when using the @TableGenerator to ensure that the id wouldn't jump from 1, 2,... to 32,xxx, 65,xxx,... after a jvm restart?

Is there a design reason for the need to specify the allocationSize?

This snippet would produce the jumping ids

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;
```

Here's the modified snippet that produces the properly sequenced ids

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "account_generator")
@TableGenerator(name = "account_generator", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate caches a block of ids for performance reasons. It allocates several ids from database, keeps  and if these run out it allocates another block from sequence (thus increasing the sequence value)

Comment: just be aware you are taking a performance hit for persisting objects when using a block size of 1

Comment: @Justin: Why is it that specifying a block size of 1 causes a performance hit??

Comment: @n_g: For every new object to persist you need an id, so hibernate does a select and an update to the id table. If you increase the block size, hibernate caches (i.e. reserves) as many ids as this block size is and only queries/updates the id table if this cache is used up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not claiming it is the case but this might be a bug in the underlying generator used by Hibernate. See for example [this post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=980566&start=0) on Hibernate's forums that describes a weird behavior, the issues mentioned in the comments of the [New (3.2.3) Hibernate identifier generators](http://relation.to/2082.lace) or existing issues in [Jira](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH).

My suggestion would be to identify the generator used in your case and to search for an existing issues or to open a new one.